# Scope Search Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a scope configured to search a database on a name. The scope looks like:

```
class AdminVerified
  scope :search, lambda {|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
end
```

I want to call this scope in a form. Does anyone know how to call a scope in a form. I want to create a form_tag that has a text field that its parameters call the scope. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a form for searching..

```
<%= form_tag("/search") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

In controller

```
def search
  @results = AdminVerified.search(params[:search])
end
```

In view

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.field_1 %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps